# ActualWidth and ActualWidth is 0

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8

First of all YES I've read all the suggested "Questions that may already have your answer", so I belive this is not a dublicate.

I have this grid on a Page:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="Please sign below." Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Image x:Name="SignImage" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid Background="Transparent" Grid.Row="2" Margin="12,0,10,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button x:Name="ClearButton" Content="Clear" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button x:Name="OkButton" Content="Ok" Grid.Column="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Then this CodeBehind:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
    //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
}
```

....

```
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show($"SignImage.ActualWidth: {SignImage.ActualWidth}, SignImage.ActualWidth: {SignImage.ActualWidth} ");
}
```

The problem is that the size of my Image is 0 (zero).

How do I make my Image fill out the cell I've placed it in?

Comment: Well, it's empty, of course it's 0. Why not set it's and it's Grid's alignments to stretch?

Comment: Well, it's empty, of course it's 0. So far so good. But how do I make it "fill out" the grid cell?

Comment: Actually, scratch that. Image without any content will always have 0 size. Why do you need it to have more? You won't see it anyway.

Comment: I'm createing a page where you can sign some thing. So I need to create a WriteableBitmap with the size of that image.

Comment: Until you have an actual image you won't know the size. If you need maximum size available you can take the size of a Grid that contains the Image, but you'll need to set Grid's VerticalAlignment and HorizontalAlignment to `Stretch`. But that's strange anyway. Just provide some `Source` for your Image and it will have some size.

Comment: It's the other way arround! The size go the cell defines the size of the source. The actual image you draw with your finger

Comment: I cant see where you're setting the `source` of the image. Images have a setting `Stretch` which you can use to fill the space available

Comment: In my demo app I dont det the source. The source of the image would be a WriteableBitmap with the correct source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First there is difference between * and Auto. Please do check the size of the main grid. "*" means stretch to fill the available space, and is a fraction, so if one row is * and the other row is 2* then the second row will be twice the size of the first row.

Auto means it takes whatever/or only space it needs.

If you have set the size of whole Grid to a small height then there will be a problem. Set the MinHeight for the Main Grid component.

Second you have not set the image for **SignImage** with a size which mean you will obviously get ActualWidth and ActualHeight as Zero. The image tag is empty in which no Source is set.

```
<Image x:Name="SignImage" Source="C:\Users\Administrator\Pictures\user-thumbnail.png"/>
```

Check after setting the image source if you are getting the ActualWidth and ActualHeight

Have a look at this image I have written your code. You can see that for Grid 0 and 2 there is Height set for Grid 1 there is no Height set as you have written * for it so it is necessary to set the height to parent.
[image]

Now look at this image I have set the height for the parent element as 200 and hence you can see the Gird 1 is visible and the height is not 0.
[image]

So it is necessary to set the height or set the image source for the height not to be zero.

Comment: Yuo missed the entire point. I need to create a membitmap with the size of the of my imagecontrol.

Comment: Have you set the size of the main grid?

Comment: Nope, but you can get that via Grid.parrent